# Node::access with anonymous user

Tags: nodes

I want to add a CSS class in `hook_preprocess_html()`, which indicates that logged-in users have access to the content and that anonymous users don't have access to it.

First I get the node with `$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');`
and I check the anonymous users have accessto the node.

```
  if ($node) {
    $guest = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::getAnonymousUser();

    if (!$node->access("view", $guest)) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'membercontent';
    }
  }
```

In every case, it returns `TRUE`. I verified `$guest` is a valid account and its ID is 0.
Does anybody know what is the problem with that?

Comment: Are anonymous users allowed to read node content in `People > Permissions` ? E.g. is `View published content` checked on this page?

Comment: Yes they are. They can view published content, but other permissions disallow it. Does $node->access("view") only check the regular view-permissions?

Comment: Almost all access checks in drupal 8 return allowed or neutral. If any access check returns allowed, access is allowed. Future neutral results do not change that. It is possible for a access check to return forbidden. This result overrides all other access results. You'll need to overhaul your permissions so that they only give correct access or add a forbidden access check.